# Oracle select all value from the next line of specified string

Tags: oracle, substring, oracle19c

I have a Varchar2(4000) column with multiline values. For example:

```
:57A:/AU063244
CTBAAU2S
:59A:
```

The content of the 57A pattern starts after ':57A:' and end with the next colon, so as you can see it'll be:

```
/AU063244
CTBAAU2S
```

The value's length of both lines is not fixed. I just know that they are separated by chr(13) and chr(10). And I want to select only the second line's value which is CTBAAU2S. How can I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Please specify your oracle version. Also what do you mean by `I want to select only the second line's value`? Your expected output is `/AU063244 CTBAAU2S` or `CTBAAU2S`?

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy I just want the second line which is CTBAAU2S, sorry for not putting it clear. Also, I'm using the 19c version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSTR` and `SUBSTR` as follows:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(YOUR_COLUMN, 
              INSTR(YOUR_COLUMN, ':57A:') + 5,
              INSTR(SUBSTR(YOUR_COLUMN, 
                           INSTR(YOUR_COLUMN,':57A:') + 5), 
                    ':') - 1
             ) AS YOUR_VALUE
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

With your example:

```
SQL> SELECT
  2  SUBSTR(':57A:/AU063244
  3  CTBAAU2S
  4  :59A:',
  5  --
  6  INSTR(':57A:/AU063244
  7  CTBAAU2S
  8  :59A:', ':57A:') + 5,
  9  --
 10  INSTR(SUBSTR(':57A:/AU063244
 11  CTBAAU2S
 12  :59A:',
 13  INSTR(':57A:/AU063244
 14  CTBAAU2S
 15  :59A:',':57A:') + 5), ':') - 1
 16  ) AS YOUR_VALUE
 17  FROM DUAL;

YOUR_VALUE
-------------------
/AU063244
CTBAAU2S


SQL>
```

Comment: Sorry for not putting it clear, I just want the second line's value which is the CTBAAU2S, not values from both lines.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

Sample data, *expanded* a little bit:

```
SQL> select * from test;

COL
---------------------------------------
:50C:
:55B:XYZ
12345W
:57A:/AU063244
CTBAAU2S
:59A:


SQL>
```

Query

- splits column value into rows (separated by CRLF)
- looks for the 2nd "row" that follows the one that contains the search string ...

  - ... while that "next row" can't begin with a colon (as it means that that particular "key value" doesn't actually have the 2nd row)

Adjust it, if needed.

```
SQL> set ver off
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select level lvl,
  3            regexp_substr(col, '[^('||chr(13)||chr(10)||')]+', 1, level) val
  4     from test
  5     connect by level <= regexp_count(col, chr(13)||chr(10)) + 1
  6    )
  7  select t.val
  8  from temp t
  9  where t.lvl = (select b.lvl + 1
 10                 from temp b
 11                 where instr(b.val, ':&search_for:') > 0
 12                )
 13    and substr(t.val, 1, 1) <> ':';
Enter value for search_for: 57A

VAL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CTBAAU2S

SQL> /
Enter value for search_for: 50C

no rows selected

SQL> /
Enter value for search_for: 55B

VAL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12345W

SQL>
```